# JBOSS deployment: java.lang.LinkageError: com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl

Tags: java, xml, soap, jboss, linkageerror

I am deploying war with its external libraries kept at the server in a module.xml.
Deployment goes successful, but as I move to hit the service using SOAPUI. I get this Linkage error. While browsing, I have seen that it may be dues to conflict of rt.jar and saaj-impl.jar.

Below is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml(sdaf.test is custom path for module where main is present under which the 3rd party jars are kept) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>        
        <dependencies>          
            <module name="sdaf.test" />     
            <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" />  
        </dependencies>     
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Below is module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="sdaf.test">
    <resources>
 <resource-root path="activation.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="hibernate-core.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="javaee.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="saaj-impl.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="stax-ex.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="streambuffer.jar"/>
      <resource-root path="jaxp-ri-1.4.5.jar"/>
       <resource-root path="jaxws-rt.jar"/>
      <resource-root path="jsr181-api.jar"/>
    </resources>
 <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.ws.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
         <module name="com.sun.xml.bind"/>
        <module name="javax.jws.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```